# check null value in linq

Tags: c#, linq

How do i check null in linq query??

here is the code:

```
 var query = _orderRepository.Table;
        query = query.Where(o => o.AccountId == accountId);
        var result = from d in query
                     where d.CreatedOnUtc != null
                     select d;


        if (result != null)
        {


        }
        //var MinDate = from d in query
        //              where (d.CreatedOnUtc == null ? d.CreatedOnUtc == null : d.CreatedOnUtc == (from d1 in query select d1.CreatedOnUtc).Min())
        //            select d.CreatedOnUtc;
        //var MaxDate = from d in query
        //              where (d.CreatedOnUtc == null ? d.CreatedOnUtc == null : d.CreatedOnUtc == (from d1 in query select d1.CreatedOnUtc).Max())
        //              select d.CreatedOnUtc;

        var rateSum = (query.Sum(d => d.OrderSubtotal));
        var MinDate = (from d in query select d.CreatedOnUtc).Min();
        var MaxDate = (from d in query select d.CreatedOnUtc).Max();
        decimal qry;
        //query = query.Where(c =>
        //((DbFunctions.DiffDays(MinDate, MaxDate) == 0) ? rateSum : (DbFunctions.DiffDays(MinDate, MaxDate) / 30 == 0) ? "rateSum" ? "(rateSum / (DbFunctions.DiffDays(MinDate, MaxDate) / 30)"));
        if ((DbFunctions.DiffDays(Convert.ToDateTime(MinDate), Convert.ToDateTime(MaxDate)) == 0))
            //if ((SqlFunctions.DateDiff("", Convert.ToDateTime(MinDate), Convert.ToDateTime(MaxDate)) == 0))
            {
            qry = (rateSum);
        }
        else if ((DbFunctions.DiffDays(Convert.ToDateTime(MinDate), Convert.ToDateTime(MaxDate)) / 30 == 0))
        {
            qry = (rateSum);

        }
        else
        {
            qry = Convert.ToDecimal(rateSum / (DbFunctions.DiffDays(MinDate, MaxDate) / 30));
        }

        var orderCount = qry;
        return orderCount;
```

can anyone guide me how do i check null in rateSum ,MinDate  and MaxDate  when query  value is null.???

i am tring a lot but not working so any suggestions???

Comment: decimal type is OrderSubtotal

Comment: @Nkosi CAN YOU POST A ANSWER??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Messy layout and poor spelling and punctuation convey hastiness and lack of reflection on the problem in hand. You only ask us how to do something without actually *explaining* your problem. Chances are, if you calmly try to explain it, you'll also find the solution.

Comment: CreatedOnUtc is the datetime so when i check it gives me error

Comment: if ((DbFunctions.DiffDays(Convert.ToDateTime(MinDate), Convert.ToDateTime(MaxDate)) == 0))  is error

Comment: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow rateSum to be nullable decimal.
I use this specially in outer joined queries to avoid ugly `the cast to value type failed...` exception.

```
var rateSum = (query.Sum(d => (decimal?)d.OrderSubtotal));
```

Then you can check rateSum for null
When I need to check that query is not empty, I use `query.Count()`


To be able to check MinDate for null just apply the same system:

```
var MinDate = (from d in query select (DateTime?)d.CreatedOnUtc).Min();
```

Comment: the error come s if ((DbFunctions.DiffDays(Convert.ToDateTime(MinDate), Convert.ToDateTime(MaxDate)) == 0))

Comment: how do i check DiffDays??

Comment: do not perform DiffDays if MinDate or MaxDate is null

Comment: this is the sql query i want to implement same things in linq..so can you give me a proper solutions??

Comment: can you write down??

Comment: CreatedOnUtc is the datetime so when i check it gives me error –

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt the following approach work for you

```
    var rateSum = query.Where(d=>d.OrderSubtotal !=null).Sum(d => d.OrderSubtotal);
```

**PS: you will need to change OrderSubtotal to decimal? (nullable decimal) if the value is nullable in DB**

and for MinDate as follows

```
    var MinDate = query.Where(d=>d.CreatedOnUtc !=null).Min(d =>d.CreatedOnUtc);
```

Comment: how do i check for MinDate ?

Comment: with out change this how do i check PS: you will need to change OrderSubtotal to decimal? (nullable decimal) if the value is nullable in DB??

Comment: this is the sql query i want to implement same things in linq..so can you give me a proper solutions??

Comment: CreatedOnUtc is the datetime so when i check it gives me error –

Comment: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.

Comment: if ((DbFunctions.DiffDays(Convert.ToDateTime(MinDate), Convert.ToDateTime(MaxDate)) == 0))

Comment: can anyone fix this problem for me